# Swap Fn and Ctrl keys without accessing BIOS

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

I am a Software Engineer, and the Fn and Ctrl keys in my laptop are swapped, and it is very annoying. And I am unable to access BIOS, as it is password protected by the admin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So ask your admin to sort it for you.

Comment: Can you pop off the key caps and switch 'em? Of course, if it's a corporate machine, your job might be on the block for any willful damage...